# Applying css on SVG,used as object in html file

Tags: svg

Hi i am trying my hand on svg and new to it.though i landed to a situation where i want to change the css value and fill of svg file.but its not working.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
 .cp2{display: none;}
    .cloud:hover .cp2{ 
  fill:#ffffff;
  stroke:#0fc5a5;
  stroke-dasharray:90;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;  
  -webkit-animation:dash 1s linear forwards;
  -o-animation:dash 1s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation:dash 1s linear forwards;
  animation:dash 1s linear forwards;
  pointer-events:all;
 }
 .cloud:hover .cp1{display: none;}    
    </style>
    <h2>SVG</h2>
    <div class="cloud">
       <object  width="40" height="35" type="image/svg+xml"  data="new.svg"></object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- And svg file name as "new.svg" as below-->

<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="cc" class="cc" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
     <path class="cp1" d="M19,18H6A4,4 0 0,1 2,14A4,4 0 0,1 6,10H6.71C7.37,7.69 9.5,6 12,6A5.5,5.5 0 0,1 17.5,11.5V12H19A3,3 0 0,1 22,15A3,3 0 0,1 19,18M19.35,10.03C18.67,6.59 15.64,4 12,4C9.11,4 6.6,5.64 5.35,8.03C2.34,8.36 0,10.9 0,14A6,6 0 0,0 6,20H19A5,5 0 0,0 24,15C24,12.36 21.95,10.22 19.35,10.03Z" />  
   <path class="cp2" d="M9,12C9.53,12.14 9.85,12.69 9.71,13.22L8.41,18.05C8.27,18.59 7.72,18.9 7.19,18.76C6.65,18.62 6.34,18.07 6.5,17.54L7.78,12.71C7.92,12.17 8.47,11.86 9,12M13,12C13.53,12.14 13.85,12.69 13.71,13.22L11.64,20.95C11.5,21.5 10.95,21.8 10.41,21.66C9.88,21.5 9.56,20.97 9.7,20.43L11.78,12.71C11.92,12.17 12.47,11.86 13,12M17,12C17.53,12.14 17.85,12.69 17.71,13.22L16.41,18.05C16.27,18.59 15.72,18.9 15.19,18.76C14.65,18.62 14.34,18.07 14.5,17.54L15.78,12.71C15.92,12.17 16.47,11.86 17,12M17,10V9A5,5 0 0,0 12,4C9.5,4 7.45,5.82 7.06,8.19C6.73,8.07 6.37,8 6,8A3,3 0 0,0 3,11C3,12.11 3.6,13.08 4.5,13.6V13.59C5,13.87 5.14,14.5 4.87,14.96C4.59,15.43 4,15.6 3.5,15.32V15.33C2,14.47 1,12.85 1,11A5,5 0 0,1 6,6C7,3.65 9.3,2 12,2C15.43,2 18.24,4.66 18.5,8.03L19,8A4,4 0 0,1 23,12C23,13.5 22.2,14.77 21,15.46V15.46C20.5,15.73 19.91,15.57 19.63,15.09C19.36,14.61 19.5,14 20,13.72V13.73C20.6,13.39 21,12.74 21,12A2,2 0 0,0 19,10H17Z" />
</svg>
```

Now i want fill and stroke of svg file to change on div (with class="cloud") hover.Altough i am able to do same if directly apply the style in svg file only and hover the svg is changing its color.please suggest if i can do it without any javascript.i only want to use css not javascript to achieve this.

Comment: You need to move your CSS into the SVG document. CSS does not apply cross document.

Comment: thanks Robert.i will try by moving it to SVG file only.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do it.  CSS doesn't apply across document boundaries.  You can't style your SVG from CSS in the HTML.

However, if you are just working with single colour icons, you can use the special colour name `currentColor` which allows the SVG to "inherit" the current colour from the HTML.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
    .cloud {
        color: blue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .cloud:hover {  
        color: red;
    }
    .cloud use {
       fill: currentColor;
    }
    </style>
    <h2>SVG</h2>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="cloud">
       <use xlink:href="new.svg#cloudicon"/>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

**new.svg**

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="cc" class="cc" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <g id="cloudicon">
    <path class="cp1" d="M19,18H6A4,4 0 0,1 2,14A4,4 0 0,1 6,10H6.71C7.37,7.69 9.5,6 12,6A5.5,5.5 0 0,1 17.5,11.5V12H19A3,3 0 0,1 22,15A3,3 0 0,1 19,18M19.35,10.03C18.67,6.59 15.64,4 12,4C9.11,4 6.6,5.64 5.35,8.03C2.34,8.36 0,10.9 0,14A6,6 0 0,0 6,20H19A5,5 0 0,0 24,15C24,12.36 21.95,10.22 19.35,10.03Z" />  
    <path class="cp2" d="M9,12C9.53,12.14 9.85,12.69 9.71,13.22L8.41,18.05C8.27,18.59 7.72,18.9 7.19,18.76C6.65,18.62 6.34,18.07 6.5,17.54L7.78,12.71C7.92,12.17 8.47,11.86 9,12M13,12C13.53,12.14 13.85,12.69 13.71,13.22L11.64,20.95C11.5,21.5 10.95,21.8 10.41,21.66C9.88,21.5 9.56,20.97 9.7,20.43L11.78,12.71C11.92,12.17 12.47,11.86 13,12M17,12C17.53,12.14 17.85,12.69 17.71,13.22L16.41,18.05C16.27,18.59 15.72,18.9 15.19,18.76C14.65,18.62 14.34,18.07 14.5,17.54L15.78,12.71C15.92,12.17 16.47,11.86 17,12M17,10V9A5,5 0 0,0 12,4C9.5,4 7.45,5.82 7.06,8.19C6.73,8.07 6.37,8 6,8A3,3 0 0,0 3,11C3,12.11 3.6,13.08 4.5,13.6V13.59C5,13.87 5.14,14.5 4.87,14.96C4.59,15.43 4,15.6 3.5,15.32V15.33C2,14.47 1,12.85 1,11A5,5 0 0,1 6,6C7,3.65 9.3,2 12,2C15.43,2 18.24,4.66 18.5,8.03L19,8A4,4 0 0,1 23,12C23,13.5 22.2,14.77 21,15.46V15.46C20.5,15.73 19.91,15.57 19.63,15.09C19.36,14.61 19.5,14 20,13.72V13.73C20.6,13.39 21,12.74 21,12A2,2 0 0,0 19,10H17Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul,i was wondering if i will be able to implement animation on it..like linear translate ease for color changing with this. [**`.cloud use {
       fill: currentColor;
    }`**
]

Comment: `.cloud:hover { color: red; transition: color 2s; }`

Comment: Paul you are a saviour,i was trying to display cp1 first then on hover cp2. i tried like **`<use xlink:href="new.svg#cp1"/>`**.now i am getting cp1.although in this way i will not have cp2 on hover. need your input

Comment: also can we have chaining of ids for child within something like **`<use xlink:href="new.svg#cloudicon#cp1"/>`** where cp1 is id for cp1 class in group "cloudicon".

Comment: You would need to change `class="cp1"` to `id="cp1"` in the SVG and link to `new.svg#cp1` etc.  You would also need to have two `<use>` elements. One for each icon. Then switch the visibility of the `<use>` elements.  We are talking about a completely different problem now, so if you have more issues you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: thanks paul for all the help..i will try it. and will raise new question if have any more issues..